# Getting the unique names of a specific value from several keys of a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, unique

I have some data on a dictionary. Each key in the dictionary has several values, one of them is called 'state' which can be equal to Georgia, Washington, etc. I want to get the unique states. I tried doing this but I get an incorrect syntax error

```
s = set( value for key in r value = key['state'] )
```

How can I get all the states?

Edit:

The data structure I have is actually a list of dictionaries so I want to get the values of r[0]['state'], r[1]['state'], etc and make an unique list.

Comment: Is the values of key `state`  iterable? Can you add your value to the question?

Comment: Can you post the dictionary that you're using?

Comment: What do you mean by unique states?

Do they key values change? Or does 'State' include a list of all states?

Comment: The dictionary is a little big. Maybe I can show one of the keys. If the dictionary is r then if I print r[0]['state'] I get Georgia. I want to get an unique list of the states that appear on the state value of every key.

Comment: @Atirag So is `r` a list of dictionaries?

Comment: @Kasramvd Yes, you're right. I didn't realize that. In this case, should I loop over all the dictionaries? How can I do that efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment since you have a list of dictionaries you can use `map` function with passing `dict.get` method to it, to get all `state` values then you can loop over the values within a `set` :

```
s = set( value for value in map(lambda x:x.get('state'),r))
```

Or for get ride of `lambda` function you can use `operator.itemgetter` :

```
from operator import itemgetter
s = set( value for value in map(itemgetter('state'),r))
```

Comment: I got this error TypeError: descriptor 'get' requires a 'dict' object but received a 'str'

Comment: Just one more question just in case. Is there a way I can get a count of the amount of times a state shows up modifying that code slightly? For example the amount of times Alabama was found

Answer (score 0):

So you have a dictionary, and each key-value pair has another dictionary inside `value`, where one of the keys for these "inner" dictionary is `state`?

In that case:

```
my_dict = {'somekey': {'a':1,'b':2, 'state':'georgia'}, 'otherkey': {'a':1,'b':2, 'state':'washington'}}
[val['state'] for key, val in my_dict.iteritems()]
['georgia', 'washingon']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing at your data structure, but if it's like this:

```
r = {'home': {'address': '123 Oak Avenue', 'city': 'My town', 'state': 'State'},
     'work': {'address': '456 Main Street', 'city': 'Big city', 'state': 'State'}}
```

then you can use this to retrieve the states:

```
s = set(r[key]['state'] for key in r)
```